# Deriving the Cointegrating Equation in a VECM model

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, eviews

I am teaching myself econometrics and I am having trouble understanding how the cointegrating equation in VECM is derived.

Lets say we have two variables, Consumption and Income. As I understand it, to derive the long run equation I would run OLS on the equation: log(Consumption) = log(Income). However, when I run the two variable VECM in Eviews, I get different coefficients than when I estimate the aforementioned equation by itself, using the same data. I understand that the signs need to be reversed but the values are also different. Can someone please what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: On the left side is the equation estimated by itself. On the right side is the VECM
[image]

Comment: Can you show the estimates in each case?

Comment: Hi, I have added them to the original post. Thank you

Comment: VECM does not imply logs. So if you apply vecm estimated in level to running regression in logs you will of course see different results

Comment: Understood. However that's not what I've done - I've estimated both equations using logs(I downloaded the data as logs). I think that I am misspecifying something which is what I'm hoping someone can help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VECM estimation probably uses the Johansen MLE procedure, which can give quite different results than OLS even though they are both super-consistent.  See [Gonzalo: Five alternative methods of estimating long-run equilibrium relationships](http://www.eco.uc3m.es/~jgonzalo/teaching/PhDTimeSeries/gonzalojec94.pdf).